# Android: set color programatically from XML color constants

Tags: java, android, colors

Trying to set a color which is defined in res/values/colors.xml to an object,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <drawable name="listViewSelected">@android:color/holo_blue_light</drawable>
  <drawable name="listViewPressed">@android:color/holo_green_light</drawable>
  <drawable name="pagerTabStrip">#2B3333</drawable>
  <!--<drawable name="pagerTabStrip">#353F3E</drawable>-->
  <drawable name="tableHead">#FF444444</drawable>

</resources>
```

I can not figure out why it is not working, 
I tried a lot of approaches `(getResources(), Color.parseColor(), ...)`

How do I set the color "tableHead" e.g. to a TextView?

tv.setBackgroundColor(????);

Comment: you want to set colour to the Text of the TextView or background of textview?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Color entries should be like this

`<color name="tableHead">#FF444444</color>`

and use `tv.setBackgroundResource(R.color.tableHead);`

Comment: I don´t know why, but I defined my "color" as a "drawable" :-/   you are right, but I have to set the color like this >> getResources().getColor(R.color.tableHead) <<

Answer (score 10):

Use,..

```
Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd");
```

like,

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```

OR......................

Get a handle to the root layout used, then set the background color on that. The root layout is whatever you called setContentView with.

// Now get a handle to any View contained 
  // within the main layout you are using

```
 View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout);
```

// Find the root view

```
 View root = someView.getRootView()
```

// Set the color

```
  root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tableHead));
```

And guess what your colors.xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="tableHead">#FF444444</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your color.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="tableHead">#FF444444</color>
</resources>
```

How you will use this color to set in textview: Like this

```
tv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tableHead));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
tv.setBackgroundResource(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly modify your color.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="listViewSelected">@android:color/holo_blue_light</drawable>
  <color name="listViewPressed">@android:color/holo_green_light</drawable>
  <color name="pagerTabStrip">#2B3333</drawable>
  <!--<color name="pagerTabStrip">#353F3E</drawable>-->
  <color name="tableHead">#FF444444</drawable>

</resources>
```

For setting the textview background color you can do like

```
tv.setBackgroundColor(R.color.tableHead);
```

Additionally for setting the textview textcolor you can do like

```
tv_empty.setTextColor(R.color.tableHead)
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a color in color constants like

```
<color name="error_red_color">#f00</color>
```

then it can be set as following -

```
tv.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.error_red_color))
```

or

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.error_red_color, null))
```

Other ways are -

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(100,100,100));
```